# Toolbar below ListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, toolbar

I am working on an application that involves me having to place a toolbar at the bottom of each activity. The toolbar will have 4 buttons on it, each starting new activities.

I am just wondering, and I apologize for how general the question, is there a proper way to go about implementing this? my plan was to but a linear layout element in each xml layout file with horizontal orientation. Then four button elements inside of that...

It seems like a huge amount of work considering I will have a lot of activities..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want sounds a lot like Android's ActionBar. Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for a guide to its usage. If you use this, your  app will look and feel more consistent with the operating system, as so many apps now use the ActionBar (which is a lot of them), and you gain a lot of power for what you want to show there, and how you want to do it.

ActionBar was only introduced in Android version 3 (Honeycomb), but there's a compatibility library, [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.actionbarsherlock.com) which allows you to use it in older versions of Android as well.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, I like how Google are pushing for more developers to make use of the action bar in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a same xml for various views. So I suggest creating a generic xml, then using `Inflaters` and other resources as strings, xmls etc. to prepare the generic xml whenever any `Activity` is loaded. So you can reuse it the xml.